# Formality in comparative structures

Tags: formal-language

1. In addition, dramatic differences are not seen in the amount of leisure time men and women expended during the period examined, but men tended to use more time for this than **women**.
2. In addition, dramatic differences are not seen in the amount of leisure time men and women expended during the period examined, but men tended to use more time for this than **women did**.

I know that the second comparative structure is more formal, but is the first one too informal for IELTS writing?

Comment: I think it's just the opposite. "than women did" is a tad colloquial.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice - Not to me - perhaps a transatlantic difference?

Comment: @KateBunting Perhaps. How do you hear these?  "He paid more than they" vs "He paid more than they did"  Is one more formal than the other?

Comment: According to the Cambridge Dictionary, the structure using **subject pronoun + be/modal verb/auxiliary verb** is more formal than using **object pronoun**. Here's the [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting). What do you think?

Comment: Do you mean _taller than I am_ being more formal than _taller than me_? Yes, I agree. Perhaps that's why _than women did_ feels more 'correct' to me, though I agree with @TimRonsomesdevice that _more than they_ sounds formal.

Comment: @KateBunting I think that's because "they" is a subject pronoun and not an object pronoun. If it were "He paid more than them," it would sound a lot less formal. "He paid more than they did" seems to be somewhere in between

Comment: Wow I didn't even know that _taller than they_ is grammatical. Thanks guys.

But what about the original question, do you think using object pronouns is too informal for IELTS writing?

Comment: "Taller than they" is grammatical but in my opinion falls into the "hypercorrect" category.  I know very few people who would say it, and they  happen to be people who would consider "taller than them" ungrammatical.

Comment: I have no experience with IELTS.